# Is the second covariant derivative linear in all of its inpus

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry

I know that the second covariant derivative is defined as:

$$\nabla^2_{u, v}w = \nabla_u \nabla_v w - \nabla_{\nabla_u v} w $$

However, if I consider it as a function of $u, v, w$, I'd like to figure out which of its inputs are linear. I know by analogy that the first covariant derivative is not linear in $w$ (but it is additive). So is the second covariant derivative linear in $u$ and $v$ but not in $w$ as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The covariant derivative is linear in $w$, but not linear over smooth functions. This can be phrased as the fact that $\nabla w$ is a tensor field. Simiearly, the second covariant derivative is linear in all three entries and linear over smooth functions in $u$ and $v$ (but not in $w$). Again this can be phrased as the fact that $\nabla^2 w$ defines a tensor field.

Comment: I'm not sure by what you mean by linear in $w$ but not linear over smooth functions. I thought that $\nabla_u(w_1 + w_2) = \nabla_u w_1 + \nabla_u w_2$, but for example $\nabla_u (2w) \ne 2 \nabla_u w$

Comment: A constant multiple does come out of the covariant derivative. (And in the case you mention, this follows from $2w=w+w$.) The difference between the two "slots" comes only from the behavior under multiplication by a smooth function rather than a constant.

Comment: Wow yea, I really should have realised that. Thank you so much for being so helpful :)